# WebGL - which API to use?

Tags: opengl-es, webgl, vertex-array, vertex-attributes

I want to draw multiple polygon shapes (where each shape has it's own set of vertices).
I want to be able to position these shapes independently of each other.

Which API can i use to set the a_Position for the vertex shader?

- A) gl.vertexAttrib3f
- B) gl.vertexAttribPointer + gl.enableVertexAttribArray

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question makes it sound like you're really new to WebGL? Maybe you should [read some tutorials](http://games.greggman.com/game/webgl-fundamentals/)? But in answer to your question:

`gl.vertexAttrib3f` only lets you supply a single constant value to a GLSL attribute so you'll need to use `gl.vertexAttribPointer` and `gl.enableVertexAttribArray`. You'll also need to set up buffers with your vertex data.

`gl.vertexAttrib3f` only point is arguably to let you pass in a constant in the case that you have a shader that uses multiple attributes but you don't have data for all of them. For example lets say you have a shader that uses both textures and so needs texture coordinates and it also has vertex colors. Something like this

vertex shader

```
attribute vec4 a_position;
attribute vec2 a_texcoord;
attribute vec4 a_color;

varying vec2 v_texcoord;
varying vec4 v_color;

uniform mat4 u_matrix;

void main() {
  gl_Position = u_matrix * a_position;

  // pass texcoord and vertex colors to fragment shader
  v_texcoord = a_texcoord;
  v_color = v_color;
}
```

fragment shader

```
precision mediump float;

varying vec2 v_texcoord;
varying vec4 v_color;

uniform sampler2D u_texture;

void main() {
   vec4 textureColor = texture2D(u_texture, v_texcoord);

   // multiply the texture color by the vertex color
   gl_FragColor = textureColor * v_color;
}
```

This shader requires vertex colors. If your geometry doesn't have vertex colors then you have 2 options (1) use a different shader (2) turn off the attribute for vertex colors and set it to a constant color, probably white.

```
gl.disableVertexAttribArray(aColorLocation);
gl.vertexAttrib4f(aColorLocation, 1, 1, 1, 1);
```

Now you can use the same shader even though you have no vertex color data.

Similarly if you have no texture coordinates you could pass in a white 1 pixel shader and set the texture coordinates to some constant.

```
gl.displayVertexAttribArray(aTexcoordLocation);
gl.vertexAttrib2f(aTexcoordLocation, 0, 0); 

gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, some1x1PixelWhiteTexture);
```

In that case you could also decide what color to draw with by setting the vertex color attribute.

```
gl.vertexAttrib4f(aColorLocation, 1, 0, 1, 1);  // draw in magenta
```